# Mariadb init without root in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, installation, mariadb, root

i try to create a mariadb 10.4.10 docker image. In the dockerfile i just install mariadb into the the image. The dockerfile inherits from my personal custom alpine images, where the user "appuser" will be created.

```
FROM nwo/alpine:latest

LABEL MAINTAINER="dideldumm <123@abc.de>"

ARG IMAGE_NAME=nwo/mariadb
ARG IMAGE_VERSION=1.1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add mariadb \
    mariadb-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ./setup/setup.sql /home/appuser/app/setup.sql
COPY ./setup/start.sh /home/appuser/app/start.sh

RUN chown appuser:appuser /home/appuser/app/start.sh /home/appuser/app/setup.sql


RUN mkdir /home/appuser/data/db \
    && mkdir /home/appuser/data/log \
    && touch /home/appuser/app/mariadb.pid \
    && touch /home/appuser/app/mariadb.socket \
    && chown -R appuser:appuser /home/appuser/data/db \
    && chown -R appuser:appuser /home/appuser/data/log \
    && chown -R appuser:appuser /home/appuser/app/mariadb.socket \
    && chown -R appuser:appuser /home/appuser/app/mariadb.pid

USER appuser

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/appuser/app/start.sh"]
```

In the start.sh script i create the mariadb.cnf.

```
echo "Create mariadb configuration file"
echo "[mysqld]" > /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "port=3306" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "socket=/home/appuser/app/mariadb.socket" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "pid-file=/home/appuser/app/mariadb.pid" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "datadir=/home/appuser/data/db" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "symbolic-links=0" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "bind-address=0.0.0.0" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "console=1" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "general_log=0" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "general_log_file==/home/appuser/data/log/mariadb.log" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "log_error=/home/appuser/data/log/mariadb_error.log" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "collation-server=$MDB_COLLATION" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
echo "character-set-server=$MDB_CHARACTERSET" >> /home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf
```

Afterwards i run `mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/home/appuser/data/mariadb.cnf`. In the console output i get the message that i only can access the root user with a system root account. But as you can see in the dockerfile i switch to the appuser and run start.sh afterwards, which makes it impossible to run sudo. My goal is to initialize mariadb without previleges within start.sh.

I tried to run `mysqld` with parameter `--skip-grant-tables` but then i am not able to set the root password. This result into error message `The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement` for `ALTER USER` and `SET PASSWORD` statement.

When i run a "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" before, every command (SET PASSWORD, ALTER USER) will result into `Query OK, 0 rows affected`. At least i tried to update the user with `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('test3') WHERE USER='root' AND Host='localhost';` which results in `ERROR 1348 (HY000): Column 'Password' is not updatable`.

Till yet, i have absolutly no idea, how to configure a mysql database server without root permissions.

It will be great, if you have a solution for me.

Regards

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution by myself. The first issue was, that in my environment just "root" is beeing created and no second user. Don't know why, but i let run a script afterwards which will do that, so it's not so important to me. 
To get the "old style" 10.3 root user behaviour (which enables you to install mariadb with a non-root user) you can run `mysql_install_db` with parameter `--auth-root-authentication-method=normal`. 
Of course, you must secure your mariadb installation by yourself afterwards.

Regards Dave